# I get file of an unkown type error when I try to open csv file in Pycharm

Tags: python, csv, pycharm

I don't know how to solve this problem because I'm new to Python. Here's my problem; I want to open the csv file in the Pycharm editor to examine it as seen in the screenshot, but nothing happens when I click on it

I would appreciate your help [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSLIp.png)

Comment: Please share your csv for better analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to open this file in notepad++ to validate its format is correct.
If that works, you can try upgrading your pycharm version, pycharm supports csv formats [pycharm csv](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-tools-database-csv-formats.html). You can also try installing [csv-editor plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10037-csv-editor) in pycharm. Go to File-->Setting-->Plugins.